# Flutter Video player issue in init

Tags: flutter, video

I don`t know why this code is not working
I keep getting an exception in video player init, why is that?
What is wrong with my code?
Flutter offical website : pub.dev says i did,
The video player is the latest version and the flutter version is 2.2.3 the most recent.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dejyd.png
error : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bb3lD.jpg)

And this is my code

```
class __ContentHeaderDesktopState extends State<_ContentHeaderDesktop> {

  late VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController;
  bool _isMuted = true;

  @override
  void initState() { 
    _videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.asset(widget.featuredContent.videoUrl!);
    _videoPlayerController.addListener(() {
      setState(() { });
    });
    _videoPlayerController.initialize().then((_) => setState((){}));
    _videoPlayerController.play();

    super.initState();

  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _videoPlayerController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => _videoPlayerController.value.isPlaying 
          ? _videoPlayerController.pause()
          : _videoPlayerController.play(),
      child: Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
      children: [
        AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: _videoPlayerController.value.isInitialized 
          ? _videoPlayerController.value.aspectRatio
          : 2.344,
          child: _videoPlayerController.value.isInitialized 
            ? VideoPlayer(_videoPlayerController)
            : Image.asset(
              widget.featuredContent.imageUrl,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),          
        ),
...
```

Comment: Please include the error logs or exception you are getting, it will be easier for anyone to guess what exactly the issue is then

Comment: i`m sorry too late

Comment: Added error content